# ASP.NET MVC 5 : persisting variables in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I instantiate the 'plate' object in the GET request of the view and then access it when the form is posted. The plate object is populated with the data from the form. Can I also use it to store the passed coordinates? Or what is the idiomatic way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks!

```
public class DrawingController : Controller
{

        Plate plate;

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {   
            plate = new Plate()
            {
              Holes = new Holes()
            }
            return View(plate);
        }

        // called by ajax when user clicks on "Save" to save the input coordinates
        [HttpPost]
        public void PassCoordinates(string coordinates)
        {
          // why is plate null here?
          plate.Holes.coordinates = coordinates;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Plate plate)
        {
         // I want to access plate.Holes.coordinates that I set in 'PassCoordinates'
         // how can I achieve this?
        }
}
```

Comment: You can set `plate` as a static variable, then it will persist.  Even then though, you are going to have serious race condition issues here. Normally, storing values means persisting it via some sort of database or caching mechanism.

Comment: Why is there 2 post methods ? Can you provide your Index.cshtml ?

Comment: @0014, `PassCoordinates(string coordinates)` is called by ajax and `Index(Plate plate)` is called on form submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is the expected behavior, because **Http is stateless**.

Every time you make a call to your action method, a new object of the controller will be created. So in your case when you make the ajax call, it will create a new object of the `DrawingController` and this object will have a property of type `Plate`, but is not initialized to a `Plate` object. (*which you do in your `Index` method call*)

If you want to get the same plate instance, in your `PassCoordinates` action method you can do in different ways

1. Have your ajax call post the js object of Plate structure and have a parameter in your action method of `Plate` type. when the request is submitted, the model binder will be able to build the new object and map the values of different proeprties
2. Store the Plate object in a persistent meedium and read it. So in your Index action method, you will create the object, intialize the proprety values and store it to a db table/Session state etc. You can read it again from this place in your second action method.  Using a Static variable is another option

If you are going for the option #2 and choose to use Session/Static variable, keep in mind that you are trying to add **stateful** behavior to the stateless http. :(

IMHO, Option 1 is the way to go. **Keep the stateless behavior of Http**. Have your client code (the code which makes the ajax call) send the JS object representing the plate object and have the model binder build the object for you.

When i am looking at your code, the only thing `PassCoordinates` method is doing is, simply setting the `Holes.coordinates` property value of the Plate object (which you though will be available in the controller). You can totally remove that method and make sure that you do that in the input elements in your form so that when you submit the form to the HttpPost index action method, it will be available in the request body and model binder will map it to your Plate  parameter.

```
@model Plate
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{      
     @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Holes.coordinates)       
    <button type="submit" class="btn" >Save</button>    
}
```

This will create an input element with name `Holes.coordinates` inside the form.

```
<input id="Holes_coordinates" name="Holes.coordinates" type="text" value="">
```

Enter some value to it and submit the form. Now if you put a breakpoint in the HttpPost action method, you can see that your plate objects Hole proprety is populated and you can access the value you entered in the text box in the `coordinates` property.

Now all you have to do is, whatever client side code was making the ajax call, instead of making the ajax call, set the value of this input.

```
$("#Holes_coordinates").val("some value you want");
```

Once everything is working, you can convert the visible text box to a hidden input by simply switching the call to `HiddenFor` helper.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.Holes.coordinates)
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment :) I'm passing an html list to string coordinates and I parse it in PassCoordinates (code not shown here), yet posting it when the form is submitted would be the best thing to do. but I dont know how to do that. In your point #2, when the ajax call is made, the model object is not yet fully populated. so when I submit the form, it will be over-written, no?

Comment: I updated the answer with sample code which should work

Comment: Thanks! I'll let it you know soon, if my problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Didn't realise it was so simple :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maintain state across requests for **each user**

- Use TempData collection, and ensure you set the values each time.  They will be available on only the next requests, and if you want them to stay multiple requests, you must set them each time.
- Use Session to store values for the user's current session:
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx
- Store it in a cookie
- Store it in query string
- Store it in a database
- Store it in an in memory database or caching service
- Return the value via model to the next returned cshtml page, and place the value in a input form field, such that it is passed on the next request via the next post

Each method has advantages and disadvantages and without more information it's hard to determine what the appropriate choice is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! will definitely keep this in mind :)