# Updating a div based on a select event from KendoUI Widget

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a KendoUI search bar that has a drop down of autocompleted items based on what I type. When I type into I get a drop down menu. When I click on an item in the drop downlist, I want two things to happen. One which works, and that is loading a partial view. But, the other thing deals with updating a div element that is also in that partial view.

The partial view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Client";
}
    <div id="update">@ViewBag.name</div>
<p id="ahhh"></p>
```

External Javascript function

```
function onSelect(e) {
    $("#navResult").load('/Home/Client');
    var value = e.item.text();
    alert(value);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/someStuf",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {n: value },
        success: function (result) {
            alert("IT WORKED");
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("FAILED");
        }
    })
}
```

In the HomeController there is a method called someStuf. I am sending that item that is clicked on the event into the someStuf method.

Now here are the two controller methods that I'm working with.

```
Secretary s = new Secretary();
public ActionResult Client()
{
    ViewBag.name = s.Client;
    return PartialView();
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult someStuf(String n)
{
    s.Client = n;
    return Json(n, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

So then I update a class with that value that was passed from javascript. I then add that new value to the viewbag for the partial view Client.

Sorry for the misleading variables. Client is a type of model. Then I always have a partial view that is called client.

When I try this. The ViewBag is not showing the result that I would like. I can get the client side to send to the server. But I can't get the server to send to the client.... I bet it's something simple. But I'm trying to understand this step so I can use the same method to update id and class elements.

```
 <p class="CompanySearchBar">
                @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
.Name("companyComplete") //The name of the AutoComplete is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
.DataTextField("company") //Specify which property of the Product to be used by the AutoComplete.
.BindTo(Model)
.Filter("contains")
.Placeholder("Company name")
.Events(e => { e.Select("onSelect"); })
                 )
            </p>
```

The above code allows for a search bar with autocomplete. While typing for an item a drop down list shows up with results having the same substring. When clicking one of the results the onSelect method is activated.

Comment: So what is your problem ? with the code you provided, it will update the `ViewBag.name`to whatever `s.Client` returns. What specifically is not working ? Unrelated thing, but, the `s` object will not persist data between your 2 ajax calls. If the value of `e.item.text()` at client side is "Abc", What is your expected output ?

Comment: The view bag never updates.

Comment: But your code setting the viewbag to `s.Client`. Are you sure `s.Client` returns a valid value ? You have not shared where that property get's it's value.

Comment: Client is a prototype that returns a string. So I set it one method and call it in the other. I believe.

Comment: The `s` object will not persist between requests.  for every request a new object of `Secretary` will be created.

Comment: Here is a relevant post similar to your usecase. Hopefully it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47358969/asp-net-mvc-5-persisting-variables-in-controller/47359245#47359245

Comment: @Shyju I'm trying to understand your example. And I think I understand what you're saying. Yet, I have a hard time producing that result with the selector script that I'm using.

Comment: Am I not asking the right question?

Comment: Not really sure if this question got lost.

Answer (score 0):

you can give like this and on change event just assign a value using jquery like

```js
function onSelect(e) {
    $("#navResult").load('/Home/Client');
    var value = e.item.text();
    alert(value);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/someStuf",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {n: value },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#ahhh').text(result.NAME); //the object which you returns from the controller
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("FAILED");
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<label id=ahhh></label>
```